# How do I calculate the 25th percentile of a multi-column DataFrame that contains a non-numeric row index and null values without using a function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble figuring out the 25th percentile of an unusual DataFrame without using the df.quantile function.

The DataFrame looks similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.4, np.nan], [7.1, -4.5],
                   [np.nan, np.nan], [0.75, -1.3]],
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                  columns=['one', 'two'])


df:

      one  two
  a  1.40  NaN
  b  7.10 -4.5
  c   NaN  NaN
  d  0.75 -1.3
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Provide some data for your question, show what you tried so far. Help community to help you